# How to remove red hat icon from top left corner Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, jdialog

Is there a way of removing the rhel red hat icon from top left corner in JDialog window ?
Purpose is to have only the text "Activities".
[red hat icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4Fuy.png)

I have tried to search from where is coming that image, but no success.

Can you please help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think of of hand is the same thing as what was suggested by @user16320675. Create and use a small transparent empty image to replace the default image. This does however leave an icon sized gap between the left edge of the frame and the text. It may be a good idea to try and center the text within the title Bar.

[image]

You can try something like this provided method. Read comments in any of the following code:

```
/**
 * Replaces the Title Bar Icon with a created blank (tranparent) .png image.
 * 
 * @param comp (java.awt.Component) Any Component variable name related to 
 * the JFrame or JDialog.
 */
public void noFormIcon(java.awt.Component comp) {
    // Create an empty .png image
    java.awt.image.BufferedImage image = 
            new java.awt.image.BufferedImage(5, 5, java.awt.image.BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    java.awt.Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
    g2d.setComposite(java.awt.AlphaComposite.Clear);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 5, 5);
    g2d.dispose();

    // Apply the created Image to the Component's Parent Window.
    java.awt.Window win = javax.swing.SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(comp);
    if (win != null) {
        win.setIconImage(image);
    }
}
```

To use this method you might have something like this:

```
// Instantiate a JDialog Window:
javax.swing.JDialog dia = new javax.swing.JDialog();
dia.setTitle("Some Dialog Window"); // Set dialog title.
// Set its size:
dia.setSize(300, 200);              // Set dialog size.
dia.setAlwaysOnTop(true);           // Set 'Always On Top'
dia.setModal(true);                 // Set dialog to be Modal.
// Dispose of dialog when closed.
dia.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
dia.setLocationRelativeTo(null);    // center dialog to Screen

// Instantiate a JLabel and applpy a caption:
javax.swing.JLabel label = new javax.swing.JLabel("Some JLabel In Dialog Window");
    
// Set the Horizontal Alignment for the Caption text to be Center.
label.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JLabel.CENTER);
    
// Add the JLabel to the JDialog
dia.add(label);
    
// Replace the dialog title Bar Icon Image with an empty .png:
noFormIcon(dia);
    
// Display the dialog.
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
    dia.setVisible(true);   
});
```